# how filter object in json array by one key

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i making a system with angular 6 and i have more 100 inputs for make, but i have a lot of forms, and the forms using the some input much times.
beucause it i want create dynamic form. but i'm think how the best form to connect the configure of input to correct object.

im thinking create all definition of inputs and catch this values based object, but my definition was do it

```
 let inputs: FormBase<any>[] = [

      new InputTextForm({
        key: 'Id',
        label: 'Id',
        value: '',
        required: true,
        order: 1
      }),

      new InputTextForm({
        key: 'Nome',
        label: 'Nome',
        value: '',
        required: true,
        order: 2
      }),

      new InputTextForm({
        key: 'Descricao',
        label: 'Descricao',
        order: 3
      }),

      new InputTextForm({
        key: 'PodeFracionar',
        label: 'Pode Fracionar',
        order: 4
      }),

      new InputTextForm({
        key: 'TaxaPis',
        label: 'Taxa Pis',
        order: 5
      }),
    ];


    return inputs.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
  }
```

but name of all objects is InputTextForm, and i will need filter based on key. but how i can filter and push one InputTextForm to other array filtering by key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you already tried iterating over the array and checking the value of the `key` property each time you iterate?

Lodash's [_.forEach()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#forEach) method is very good for this. You can iterate over an object:

`_.forEach(someObject, function(value,key) { /* some function */})`

or you can iterate over an array:

`_.forEach(someArray, function(value) { if (value.key == 'someVal') {/*code*/}})`

Then inside the forEach loop you can check your values and if they match, push to your other array.

Comment: thank you very much, easy solution. i think will well i stop of programming today rs my brain are sleeping rs

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use **lodash** here array object have filter method will do the same , you may consider use native javascript function then inject a new dependency to your project that will give **same result**

```
let result = inputs.filter(i => i.key === 'TaxaPis') ; 
console.log(result);  // => [{key: 'TaxaPis', label: 'Taxa Pis',  order: 5}]
```